# Does "Kokopelli's Flute" correctly depict Kokopelli?

Tags: kokopellis-flute, will-hobbs

In [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=38561369#38561369), @BESW taught me that there is a certain way that Kokopelli - a Native American god - must be depicted.

In [*Kokopelli's Flute*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/249593.Kokopelli_s_Flute), Kokopelli is shown as both an old man named Cricket and an actual cricket. Is the way the way he is depicted in line with the respect that is required when depicting Kokopelli?

Comment: Must be depicted under what rules? Respect that is required by whom?

Comment: Required by the Native American tribes who he is a god for.